# How to do an approx match and replace with correct word in R?

Tags: r, text-mining

```
list1 <- c("prmum","prum","primium","prm","prim","primum","prem","premum",
           "wrng","wng",
           "hug","hung",
           "amut",
           "chq","chquked","cheuq","chek","cheq",
           "cus","cust",
           "cbk","cb",
           "ringirng","rining","rigirigi")


list2 <- c("premium","wrong","hang","amount","cheque","customer","callback","ringing")
dat <- as.data.frame(list1)
for(i in length(list1)){
t <- agrep(list1[i],list2,value=FALSE)
 dat[t] <- list2[i]
}
```

I have two lists one having wrong_words and other correct_words.
I am trying to do the following:

1)Take first word.
2)Do approx match from list of correct_words and get the index location.
3)Replace the wrong word with the correct word at that particular location 
in the dataframe or a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `stringdistmatrix` from package `stringdist`. It uses Levenshtein distance just like agrep. You find which word has the closest match, and replace it in your original list.

```
 library(stringdist)
 dist_mat <- stringdistmatrix(list1, list2)
 clean_list1 <- list2[apply(dist_mat, 1, which.min)]
 clean_list1
```

Now this solution may be inappropriate if you have very long lists (assume they are of length l1 and l2, you will get a matrix of size l1*l2). You may need to go through a loop to reduce memory consumption.

```
clean_list1 <- list1
for (i in length(list1)){
     dist_vect <- stringdistmatrix(list1[i],list2)
     clean_list1 <- list2[which.min(dist_vect)]
}
```